# Why aren't my Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 debugging toolbar commands showing?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2017

[image]

I can't see neither my breakpoints or any debugging commands. I have installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 and I'm currently editing a c++ source file and i'm having big troubles with debugging. Does anyone know a fix?

Comment: please try this:  Tools menu > Import and Export Settings > Reset all settings

Comment: hi, unfortunately it didn't do anything

Comment: repair or reinstall visual studio

Comment: how do i repair it?

Comment: [How to repair](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69819360/17156756).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reinstall VS** should be the last resort, you can try below suggestions first.

Please try to **restart VS** 2017 and if it doesn’t work, try to **reboot your machine**.

Please try to [**repair Visual Studio**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2017#how-to-repair) like Alan mentioned, in Visual Studio Installer > find Visual Studio 2017 > More > Repair.

Make sure that you are not using some extensions which may cause incompatibility. If you installed some **extensions**, please try to **disable** them temporary(Tools > Extensions and Updates… > find the extension you installed manually before > select it > Disable) and restart VS 2017.

Also, please try to **delete the hidden `.vs` folder** in your solution folder, and then try to start debugging again.

Sometimes, **updating VS** 2017(VS Installer > find VS 2017 > Update) will work.

Comment: Thank you very much! I actually had an update available which solved the problem for me, thanks :)!